# Phase spectrum: $\mathrm{arg}\mathcal{F}(\omega)$ or $\mathrm{-arg}\mathcal{F}(\omega)$?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, phase

Do we need minus or not?
I need to extract phase spectrum from that thing

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i\omega x}d\omega\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt$$

I can do it by taking Fourier Transform of $f(x)$, right? And phase spectrum will be:

$$S(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-i\xi x}dx $$

$$\Phi (\xi)=-\mathrm{arg}\,S(\xi)$$

I found that in book, but don't understand do we need minus
 before arg or not? I'm looking on different plots and some sources plotting with minus and some without. Help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both definitions are common. However, if you talk about the *phase*, then what is usually meant is the (frequency dependent) phase angle $\phi(\omega)$ of the Fourier transform $F(\omega)$:

$$F(\omega)=|F(\omega)|e^{j\phi(\omega)}\tag{1}$$

The negative phase $\beta(\omega)=-\phi(\omega)$ is often called the *phase shift* or *phase lag*. It is commonly used together with the *attenuation* $\alpha(\omega)$, which is the negative natural logarithm of $|F(\omega)|$:

$$\alpha(\omega)=-\log (|F(\omega)|)\tag{2}$$

$$F(\omega)=e^{-(\alpha(\omega)+j\beta(\omega))}\tag{3}$$